# mysqlhotcopy a single table

Tags: mysql

mysqlhotcopy works great for me to do the whole DB, but I can't seem to do a single table.
I thought this should work

```
/usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy mydb_cms./^SiteUsers$/ /db0/bkp --user=xxx --password=xxx --allowold --method=cp
```

When I run that I get:

```
No tables to hot-copy at /usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy line 396
```

That is the right DB and table:

```
mysql> show tables;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_mydb_cms |
+--------------------+
| SiteUsers          | 
| UserTemp           | 
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> select version();
+------------------------------+
| version()                    |
+------------------------------+
| 5.0.45                       | 
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any ideas?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around the arguments with special characters such as $.

Comment: Didn't work, I shouldn't even need the $ but mydb_cms./^SiteUsers/ doesn't work either.